# NSPopover + NSBox in dark mode tint/gamma issue

Tags: macos, cocoa, nspopover, nsvisualeffectview, nsbox

I have `NSPopover` with `NSBox` and subviews are: `MKMapView` and `NSImageView`. In dark mode the whole NSBox adds gamma/tint to all subviews. This doesn't appear in light mode (compare images below). It seems to be something with `NSVisualEffectView`. How can I prevent/disable this effect?

PS: This effect doesn't show in normal window. Only popover is affected.

[image: Dark mode]
[image: Light mode]

Code out of the box drag&drop elements. Mojave 10.14.4

```
- (IBAction)showPopover:(id)sender {
    [[self popover] showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSRectEdgeMaxX];
}
```

Edit: APR2020
According to "Adopting advanced features of the new ui of os x yosemite" ([youtube](https://youtu.be/ETzXheoGZ34?t=1755)) this happens because of some vibrancy effect of the fill color. Popover has effective appearance of `NSVibrantDarkAppearance`

```
(lldb) po [self.view .effectiveAppearance]
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : <NSCompositeAppearance: 0x60000210a940
 (
    "<NSVibrantDarkAppearance: 0x60000170b840>",
    "<NSDarkAquaAppearance: 0x60000170ae80>",
    "<NSSystemAppearance: 0x60000170afc0>"
)>
lldb) po [self.view .superview]
▿ 1 element
  ▿ 0 : Optional<NSView>
    - some : <NSPopoverFrame: 0x1020a63f0; material: Popover; blendingMode: BehindWindow; state: Active>
```

So other possible solution is to use fill color which is not vibrant.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by adding extra `NSVisualEffectView` behind the `NSBox` where blending is set to happen within window. left(with visual effect view), right (without).

[image]